# Flexbox: shrink image to fit

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to design a page with the following properties that will be used as digital signage:

- Page height is viewport height (`100vh`) so that scrolling is impossible
- Page is arranged into full-width rows
- All rows but the last are static (have pre-defined content)
- Last row (which will contain an image slideshow) should fill the remaining space in the viewport.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
div.red {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
div.blue {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
div.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62qqnx3m/6/

Clearly this is not working because `flex` is not shrinking the image div to the right size.

I can remove the `flex: 0 0 auto` from the first two divs, but then they shrink instead.

How can I force the green div/image to take up exactly what space remains, no more, no less?

So if a taller image was supplied, it would shrink even more to fit.

And if an image is *smaller* than the available space, it should simply display, with the background div still filling the available space.

It seems like `max-height:100%` would be great for this, but that also does not work.

Furthermore, I have seen examples of how to do this horizontally (which I also need, but am having less trouble with), but I can't figure out how to translate that into vertical scaling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the position of the `green` block to `relative` and the position of the image to absolute.
Also make sure the height of the `green` block is set to 100% (to take the rest of the height of the page).

This should fix the problem:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.red {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

div.blue {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

div.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's what we know:

- The page height is `100vh`
- The first row is static (`height: 100px`)
- The second row is static (`height: 150px`)
- The third row, which contains images, should fill the remaining height

I think the solution lies in basic math:

```
100vh - 100px - 150px = height of third row
```

Instead of this in your code:

```
div.green {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Try this:

```
div.green {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

img {
    height: calc(100vh - 250px);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
div.red {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
div.blue {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
/* 
div.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
img
{
  max-height: 100%;
}
*/

div.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
img {
  height: calc(100vh - 250px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/">
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/62qqnx3m/8/)

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted the third row to fill the remaining height. Here's an alternative with `height: 100%` on the image: https://jsfiddle.net/62qqnx3m/9/

Answer (score 0):

I just change the img class and add to class .green min-height: 100%; Additionally the image is responsive now with that code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
   
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  
}

div.red {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

div.blue {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

div.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
   min-height: 100%;
}

.green img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ez4pf8wp/

Added this to the img class:

```
img {
   max-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```