# Shrink flexbox image without position: relative / position: absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my site (see example at https://jsfiddle.net/xo4m391y/)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#parentDiv {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

#leftCol {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

#rightCol {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: green;
}

img {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="parentDiv">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-primary">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="leftCol">
      <img src="https://wbelajac.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/img_1117a.jpg?w=386&h=600" />
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `position: relative` and `position: absolute` ([Image flex item does not shrink height in a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630035/image-flex-item-does-not-shrink-height-in-a-flexbox;) [Flexbox: shrink image to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812393/flexbox-shrink-image-to-fit)) to get the image height to shrink to the size of the container.

This seems like an oddly hackish way of doing this, and eliminates the ability to, e.g., automatically center the image using flexbox. Is there a pure flexbox solution that does not use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to allow the image to shrink?

Additionally, if possible, I'd also like to remove the empty space on the sides of the left div when the view port is small.

Many thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: add     min-height: 0; to `#content` and simply remove position:absolute from the image (probably add     object-position: top left; to it too)

Comment: otherwise avoid img to be a flex child so you do not have deal with side effects  : possible example : https://jsfiddle.net/v2417to3/ (idem for grid display, avoid img to be a direct grid child, so you do not run into these kind of issues , best way  to cure a bug/unexpected behavior is not to trigger it )

Comment: Thank you both--I can't believe it was this simple. I probably spent more time than I should admit on this :D @Temani, any chance you could give me some intuition on why min-height: 0 on #content works?

Comment: (and @G-Cyrillus too, just noticed that in there as well)

Comment: I added a duplicate question detailling this